# How best to serve versioned S3 files from CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront distribution that has two origins in it: one origin that is a static S3 bucket (which is cached by CloudFront), and another origin that is a dynamic server (which is not cached). When users log into my application, the dynamic origin redirects users to the static, cached S3 bucket origin.

Right now, I'm handling the versioning of my S3 bucket by doing the following: I prepend the version of my code to the path of the S3 bucket on every release (so if my S3 bucket's path is normally `/static/ui`, it now becomes `/v1.2/static/ui`). The S3 bucket's cache behavior in CloudFront has the path pattern `/static/ui`, BUT the origin settings for the S3 bucket has the origin path `/v1.2`. Unfortunately, because the origin path isn't included in my cache behavior, whenever I have to change it to point to a new version, I have to invalidate my cache so that CloudFront will check the new origin path.

So, the release process goes like this:

1. I create a new version of my UI code and add it to S3, and prepend the version to my S3 bucket's path (creating a path that looks like this `/v1.2/static/ui`).
2. I change my "Origin Path" value in CloudFront associated with my S3 origin to have the new version in it (so it becomes `/v1.2`). This makes it so that all requests to my CloudFront distribution get forwarded to my origin with `/v1.2` prepended to the origin path.
3. I invalidate my CloudFront cache.

This method of versioning my UI works - but is there a better way to do it? I'd like to be able to handling versioning my S3 bucket without having to invalidate the cache every time I change versions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing "Origin Path" in CloudFront takes very long to kick in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45900704/changing-origin-path-in-cloudfront-takes-very-long-to-kick-in)

Comment: No that does not answer my question @CrisP, the answer I added below, however, does describe how I avoided cache invalidation in CloudFront altogether, by adding hashes to the static file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up versioning my S3 bucket and handling my CloudFront cache busting by doing the following:

1. I changed the way that Webpack built my static assets by adding a hash to all of the files Webpack builds except for my `index.html`, which now points to all of my hashed filenames. So, for example, previously, a given JavaScript chunk that Webpack builds was called `12.js`, and now it might be called `0b2fb3071ad992833dd4.js`, and the `index.html` now references that new hashed filename. The file hash is generated by the content within the file, and will change if the content in the file changes.
2. I make sure that when my static files are uploaded to S3, **the `index.html` file has the header `Cache-Control: no-cache` sent out with every request to the `index.html` file in my S3 bucket.** This makes it so that CloudFront never caches the `index.html` file, but will still cache the hashed filenames that the `index.html` points to.
3. I prepend the version of my static files to the S3 bucket's path where I upload my static assets (so for example, my S3 bucket's path might look like `/v1.2/static/ui/index.html` when I make a request to my `index.html` file).
4. Upon every new release, I update my CloudFront origin path for my S3 bucket origin to point to the new version of my UI (so it might change from `/v1.2` to `/v1.3`).

Because my `index.html` isn't cached by CloudFront, and because all other static files that the `index.html` points are hashed, and will have different file names upon each release (if the file changed at all), **I no longer need to manually send a CloudFront cache invalidation to my S3 bucket's path upon every release**, since upon every release, the `index.html` file will point to totally new files which will not be cached in CloudFront until users make new requests to it.

This also means that **switching my CloudFront origin path will now instantaneously switch users to different versions of my UI**, and I don't have to wait the estimated 5 minutes for a manual CloudFront cache invalidation to take effect.

Lastly, this method of cache busting also works with browser-side caching, so I was able to have files saved in my S3 bucket send a `Cache-Control: max-age=604800` header to users for all files except for my `index.html` file and enable browser-side caching for my users. The browser-side cache is invalidated when the `index.html` points to a new hashed filename for its static assets. This greatly improved the performance of my application.

This all came at the cost of not being able to cache my `index.html` file in CloudFront or the user's browser, but I think the benefits of caching this way outweigh the cost.